# Visual Studio - get the command line that will be called when selecting a build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, automation, envdte, visual-studio-extensions

I am looking for a way to determine the command line used by visual studio when selecting:

- `Build Solution` ==> Main Menu -> Build -> Build Solution
- `Build Selection` ==> Main Menu -> Build -> Build Selection
- `Compile` ==> Select a single file (C/C++) and select compile in Solution Explorer context menu

Is there a way to determine what command line is generated with each call?

For example, building a project may produce:

```
MsBuild.exe projec1.vcproj (... some parameters)
```

which, in turn calls cl.exe with some parameters.

I am wondering if there is any way to know what that original call (the MSBuild.exe one) is when I execute a build.